# Get Each Value from Object within Object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to get the key and value data from an object that is inside an object.

Example:

```
$.each(my_object, function(key, value)
{
    // some code

    if (typeof value === object)
    {
        $.each(value, function(key, value)
        {
            // do something
        )};
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

> object is not defined

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error clearly states that `object` is not defined. That is because you are trying to use it like a variable.

When checking `typeof` values you should be using a string comparison:

```
if (typeof value === 'object')
{
}
```

Comment: Oh, whoops :) Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I was thinking there was something wrong with the `value` variable that I was comparing.

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax error and object in the if condition must be string

this is the right code :

```
$.each(obj, function(key, value)
{

    if (typeof value === "object")
    {
        $.each(value, function(key, value)
        {
            console.log(value)
        }); //syntax error here
    }
});
```